# remove with verbose option

Tags: bash, shell

I've following directory structure,

```
test/{test00.txt..test99.txt}
```

If I use `rm -v -rf test`,

```
rm -v -rf test

removed 'test/test00.txt' 
removed 'test/test01.txt' 
removed 'test/test02.txt' 
removed 'test/test03.txt' 
removed 'test/test04.txt'
removed 'test/test05.txt' 
removed 'test/test06.txt' 
.... 
removed 'test/test96.txt' 
removed 'test/test97.txt' 
removed 'test/test98.txt'
removed 'test/test99.txt' 
removed directory: 'test'
```

Is there a way to hide all the verbose output generated from below `test` folder?

Can I only see something like,

```
 removed directory: 'test'
```

Comment: Which output do you want to keep and which output do you want to hide ?

Comment: Unclear.  You ask for verbose output but you do not want it?  If you just want to delete the files, but not the directory, you can do `rm -v -fr test/*`.  If you want to delete the directory and not be told about it, add `| grep -v "removed directory"`.

Comment: Don't use `rm -v`?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
rm -v -rf test | grep -v 'test/test'
```

#### Explanation

`rm -v -rf` output is followed by `|` to `grep`, which by inverse selection (`-v` switch) deletes everything, what it matches.

Comment: Maybe `grep -v "removed '"` so that it can be used on other situations.

Comment: @Philippe If he wants to remove every line of log, there is the second answer with disabling verbose mode. :)

Comment: What I meant is that `grep -v "removed '"` does the same thing as your `grep -v 'test/test'`

Comment: @Philippe It doesn't remove "removed directory: 'test'" and other nonrelated deleted files. It is not clear whether author wants these removed too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you just want to disable verbose mode so no non-error output is given back by `rm`.

To do so, just delete switch `-v`.

Your command will become

```
rm -rf test
```